# jQuery Autocomplete giving error that response is not defined

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am getting filter data form ajax call but at the time of response callback with data, code throwing error that response is undefined.

Here is the code

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) { // response undefined always 
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        q: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        // yes data contains the filtered set
        // but here response is always undefined  
        response( data ); //  here code returns error
      }
    });
  }     
});
```

I don't know same code is working and the callback issue is the first time I have ever seen.

Comment: The url only returns `["%s"]`

Comment: are you sure the response function is undefined? it looks more like the actual content isn't set properly, so the response itself is in wrong format, not the function is missing

Comment: can you do `console.log(response)` before the ajax call?

Comment: Its  not your problem.Its gives out suggestion if the length of the entered value is atlesat 3 characters long

Comment: I have debugged it and the response is always undefined even before ajax call. Request show term which is I am passing but what's wrong with the response?